# Anatomically Correct Hakutaku

Tags: anatomy, anatomically-correct

The hakutaku is a mythical creature resembling a human-faced bull with 6 horns and 9 eyes. However, these horns and eyes are not all upon the head, as you'd expect; It instead has 3 bundles, consisting of 2 horns and 3 eyes, with one on the face and the other two on the side of the body

[image]

The eyes would be able to move and see, like the eyes of the head, and the horns should be solidly attached to the body

**How would this unique animal fit together inside?**

Comment: Added a photo. You forgot to mention how the monster has a boob on its forehead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Face

The main issue with the face is the third eye. This could be solved by opening a hole in between the halves of the frontal bone, and adding in the medial structures of the orbit to both sides to make a new, symmetrical orbit

## Sides

The sides could simply have a duplicate of the frontal bone and orbits from the face, with the horns attached. They would likely need long optic nerves, which could travel alongside the spinal cord, to allow all eyes to see. The other required cranial nerves could be served by regular nervous connections. The best way to ensure a solid connection would be to add an extra rib, which would fuse to the middle of the frontal bone and connect it directly to the spine. This would also protect its optic nerves